# Different Imports Results in Different Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-import

I am using Tkinter to create a simple GUI that can request and receive messages.

Trying to display the message within a label, I have tried this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from reqrep_server import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Server")

request = Button(root, text="Request")
request.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
request.bind("<Button-1>", main)

LabelRep = Label.config(root, text=response)
LabelRep.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

which results in: `NameError: name 'response' is not defined`

And when I try:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import reqrep_server

root = Tk()
root.title("Server")

request = Button(root, text="Request")
request.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
request.bind("<Button-1>", reqrep_server.main)

LabelRep = Label.config(root, text=reqrep_server.response)
LabelRep.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

This happens: `AttributeError: module 'reqrep_server' has no attribute 'response'`

This only occurs to the **`response`** variable but not to the **`main`** function as it works fine.

The response variable is within a for-loop:

#### reqrep_server

```
for request in range(1, 3):
        print("Sending request ", request,"...")
        socket.send_string("Sensor Data")
        msg_json = socket.recv()
        ds = json.loads(msg_json)
        response = "Sensor: %s :: Data: %s :: Client: %s" % (ds['sensor'], ds['data'], ds['client'])
        print("Received reply ", request, "[", response, "]")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Which is within the **`main`** method.

How do I resolve the error and get it to work?

#### Edit:

For those who need the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tobiw\Documents\Python\Raspberry Pi\zmq\serverTTK.py", line 12, in <module>
    LabelRep = Label.config(root, text=reqrep_server.response)
AttributeError: module 'reqrep_server' has no attribute 'response'
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Both errors have similar tracebacks and file paths, just different type of errors.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations. i.e it shows your files names.

Comment: `response` is created in function so it is local variable which doesn't exist outside function. You have to use `global response` inside `main()` to get this variable outside and you have to execute `main()` before you can use `response`.

Comment: instead of `request.bind("<Button-1>", reqrep_server.main)` you can do `Button(..., command=reqrep_server.main)`

Comment: even if you assign `text=reqrep_server.response` it will not change text in `Label` after you run `main()` - Button has to execute function which executes `main()` and later replace text in `label` - `LabelRep['text'] = "new text"`

Comment: all your code will not work as you expect because GUI works different than text programs - if you run `reqrep_server.main()` then it will stop `mainloop()` so GUI will freeze. You have to change code in `reqrep_server.main` so it will works with GUI (without `sleep`) or you have to run it in thread but it will need other changes.

Comment: @furas thank you. I will keep that in mind and change my `reqrep_server` code.

Comment: It is not those of _us_ who needs the traceback. It's that of _you_ who needs it, in order to ask a good question. If you want to ask puzzles there is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get variable from function in another module it has to be global

(reqrep_server.py)

```
import time

response = 'start value' # <-- it is global variable

def main():
    global response # <-- inform function to use global variable inside function
                    #      (instead of local one)

    for x in range(10):
        response = str(x)
        print(response)

        time.sleep(1)
```

and then it will run without errors

(main.py)

```
import tkinter as tk
import reqrep_server

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

label_rep = tk.Label(root, text=reqrep_server.response)
label_rep.pack()

request = tk.Button(root, text="Request", command=reqrep_server.main)
request.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but it will not work as you expect.

You will see `'start value'` in `Label` at start because `text=reqrep_server.response` copies value from `reqrep_server.response` to `text` only once - at start - and later it will not copy this automatically.

When you click button it will freeze GUI because it blocks `mainloop` which get key/mouse events from system, sends event to widgets, updates widgets, redraw widgets, etc.

You would have to do two thinks inside main

- use `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to execute one loop.
- use `label_rep['text'] = response` to update text in label

So button should execute `main` with two arguments `root` and `label_rep` using `lambda`

```
command=lambda:reqrep_server.main(root, label_rep)
```

and you will have code

(main.py)

```
import tkinter as tk
import reqrep_server

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

label_rep = tk.Label(root) # doesn't need text at start, text=reqrep_server.response)
label_rep.pack()

request = tk.Button(root, text="Request", command=lambda:reqrep_server.main(root, label_rep))
request.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and `main` has to use them

(reqrep_server.py)

```
import time

# doesn't need this: response = 'start value'

def main(master, label):
    # doesn't need this: global response

    for x in range(10):
        response = str(x)
        print(response)

        label['text'] = response # <-- update label
        master.update() # <-- run mainloop once

        time.sleep(1)
```

---

If `main()` will need more time to work and `master.update()` will be executed less frequently then it will freeze again - and then maybe you should run `main()` in secparated `thread`.